# Running mono-service with sgen garbage collector

Tags: c#, linux, mono, mono-service

OS: Ubuntu

Is it possible to use mono-service with the sgen garbage collector? The normal garbage collector leaks all my memory until the end of the world comes. If I can't find a way to get sgen to work with mono-service I may just be stuck using a cron job instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `MONO_OPTIONS` environment variable:

```
export MONO_OPTIONS=--gc=sgen
```